# equality operators for object properties and values

Tags: javascript

Hey guys so i came across some unexpected behavior in js... and i have no idea why this happens... can someone explain to me? Thank  you

```
campaign = {
  "ppmv_ref": "1324232571",
  "type": "value off",
  "title": "20% off the weed item",
  "percentage": "20",
  "product": "weed",
  "productId": "46482649",
  "quantity": "50",
  "startDate": "10/22/2018",
  "expirationDate": "10/23/2018",
  "couponFlag": "true",
  "active": "true"
}
condition = campaign.active === true;

console.log(campaign.active)// logs true
console.log(condition); // logs false
```

Comment: `'true' !== true`..

Answer (score 1):

Because you’re comparing a string to a Boolean .

```
campaign.active === true
```

This evaluate to false, you can wrap true with quotations and this will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Because `campaign.active` store a string "true". So you should use:
`condition = campaign.active === "true"`